# Load a YAML file and replace strings in resulting dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file that I currently load into a python object using pyyaml. I'm trying to figure out how to search and replace strings before returning the result.

```
def load_and_replace_yaml(directory, file_name):
    configs_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name) + '.yml'
    f = open(configs_path, 'r')
    overrides = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    f.close()
    return overrides
```

So in the above code, I can get the yaml file as a file object, but I'm not sure how to do a find and replace on it. I could also try and do the find and replace on the resulting python dictionary `overrides` but I'm not sure how to search through the dictionary looking for strings to replace. Any help?

Comment: You can load a YAML document from a file with any name or extension, but [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is not the same as [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` at least since Sep 2006.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that f.read() returns a string that I can just call replace() on before loading into yaml.safe_load.

Comment: That is of course only so if the string occurs only once in the file, or if the instance you want to change appears at the beginning or the end of the document.